# I'm trying to set up 2 virtual host on a new VPS using apache 2.x on a Ubuntu server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Output from apache2 restart:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                [Thu Feb     09 01:19:34 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:19:34 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:19:34 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:19:34 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost xx.Xx.xxx.xxx:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:19:34 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:19:34 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
                                                                     [fail]
```

Contents of httpd.conf file:

NameVirtualHost *

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.xxxx.net
DocumentRoot /srv/www/xxxx.net/public_html/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.xxxx.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/xxxx.com/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: making changes suggested by kaji,

output from apache2 restart

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                        Warning: DocumentRoot [/www/rmusser.net] does not exist
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [error] VirtualHost *:8090 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports     with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with     a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost 71.19.144.240:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
Warning: DocumentRoot [/www/rmusser.net] does not exist
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [error] VirtualHost *:8090 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports     with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with     a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost 71.19.144.240:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 01:41:03 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
                                                                         [fail]
```

Comment: You have other config in place.  Based on your tags, you're using Ubuntu - your `NameVirtualHost` should be in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and your other `<VirtualHost>` blocks are in files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified port in virtual host defination

Try this

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www
ServerName www.example1.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8090>
DocumentRoot /www/folder
ServerName www.example2.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Didn't work, look at my edit.

Comment: Check the comment on your post from @Shane Madden